# Adding custom headers to all boto3 requests

Tags: http-headers, boto3, botocore, header-injection

I need to add some custom headers to every boto3 request that is sent out. Is there a way to manage the connection itself to add these headers?

For boto2, [connection.AWSAuthConnection](https://kite.com/python/docs/boto.connection.AWSAuthConnection) has a method build_base_http_request which has been helpful. I've yet to find an analogous function within the boto3 documentation though.

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty dated but we encountered the same issue, so I'm posting our solution.

I wanted to add custom headers to boto3 for specific requests.
I found this: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2251, and used the event system for adding the header

```
def _add_header(request, **kwargs):
    request.headers.add_header('x-trace-id', 'trace-trace')
    print(request.headers)  # for debug


some_client = boto3.client(service_name=SERVICE_NAME)
event_system = some_client.meta.events
event_system.register_first('before-sign.EVENT_NAME.*', _add_header)
```

You can try using a wildcard for all requests:

```
event_system.register_first('before-sign.*.*', _add_header)
```

*SERVICE_NAME- you can find all available services here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html

For more information about register a function to a specific event: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/events.html

Comment: Great answer, thanks for sharing the solution

Comment: This works, there is no way to pass custom data to event handlers, currently we have to do it in a non-pythonic way using global variables/queues :(

I have opened issue ticket with Boto3 developers for this exact case: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2889

Comment: @arainchi I added an answer showing how to dynamically pass in a different custom headers with every boto3 request

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @May Yaari is pretty awesome. To the concern raised by @arainchi:

> This works, there is no way to pass custom data to event handlers, currently we have to do it in a non-pythonic way using global variables/queues :( I have opened issue ticket with Boto3 developers for this exact case

Actually, we could leverage the python functional programming property: `returning a function inside a function` to get around:

In the case we want to add a custom value `custom_variable` to the header, we could do

```
some_client = boto3.client(service_name=SERVICE_NAME)
event_system = some_client.meta.events
event_system.register_first('before-sign.EVENT_NAME.*', _register_callback(custom_variable))

def _register_callback(custom_variable):
    def _add_header(request, **kwargs):
        request.headers.add_header('header_name_you_want', custom_variable)
    return _add_header
```

Or a more pythonic way using `lambda`

```
some_client = boto3.client(service_name=SERVICE_NAME)
event_system = some_client.meta.events
event_system.register_first('before-sign.EVENT_NAME.*', lambda request, **kwargs: _add_header(request, custom_variable))

def _add_header(request, custom_variable):
    request.headers.add_header('header_name_you_want', custom_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @May Yaari works great to add a constant header to every request you send. However, sometimes you need to send different headers with every request that's being sent, for example to make use of Cloudflare R2 conditional puts. For such use cases you can do the following:

```py
event_system = client.meta.events

# Moves the custom headers from the parameters to the request context
# This is done because later in the processing of the request, there is
# a parameter validation step, which doesn't allow for custom arguments.
def process_custom_arguments(params, context, **kwargs):
    if (custom_headers := params.pop("custom_headers", None)):
        context["custom_headers"] = custom_headers

# Here we extract the headers from the request context and actually set them
def add_custom_headers(params, context, **kwargs):
    if (custom_headers := context.get("custom_headers")):
        params["headers"].update(custom_headers)

event_system.register('before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject', process_custom_arguments)
event_system.register('before-call.s3.PutObject', add_custom_headers)

custom_headers = {'If-Match' : '"3858f62230ac3c9ff15f300c664312c63f"'}

client.put_object(Bucket="my_bucket", Key="my_key", Body="my_data", custom_headers=custom_headers)
```

This registers 2 handlers into the event system, one to move the custom headers from the request parameters into the request context, and another one to set it. This is done to circumvent the request parameter validation that boto3 performs.